# "If" nesting either creating Boolean expectations or matches a value and returns #N/A! adjacent to the cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am attempting to create Index and Match functions inside an "IF" Function. Generally this should be an easy task except I have more than two tables that need to be indexed as the value can be in any one of three.

I have written a formula and kept getting a match in one column but it kept prompting me to change the first If to display a boolean and that I cannot coerce the value to be a boolean. The other attempt worked and displayed the value but created a #N/A! to the right of the cell with the formula:

```
=if(A2="AP",index(FAC!$A$2:$A$45,match(A2,FAC!$E$2:$E$45)),{index(BC!$A$2:$A$45,match(A2,BC!$E$2:$E$45,0)),index(MFC!$A$2:$A$45,match(A2,MFC!$E$2:$E$45,0))})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to pnuts' nested IFERROR solution (which will work), the array concatenation method should work with:

`=IF(A2="AP",INDEX({FAC!$A$2:$A$45;BC!$A$2:$A$45;MFC!$A$2:$A$45},MATCH(A2,{FAC!$E$2:$E$45;BC!$E$2:$E$45;MFC!$E$2:$E$45},0)),)`

or perhaps just

`=IF(A2="AP",QUERY({FAC!$A$2:$E$45;BC!$A$2:$E$45;MFC!$A$2:$E$45},"select Col1 where Col5 = '"&A2&"' limit 1",0),)`